# How do I change the text value of an <input> tag sung javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to figure out this simple task. I have an input text field which I want to accept a value from and also change the value of when a link is clicked. My HTML code is below:

```
<body>
    <div id="outsideContainer">
    <div id="guessContainer">
        <h3> Guess a number between 1 and 10 </h3>

        <input id="txtfield" name="txtfield" type="text" class="value"/><br>

        <a href=" " class="query"> Submit here </a> 
    </div>
    <div id="guessShow">
        <p class="hotter hideStuff" > Getting Hotter!! </p>
        <p class="colder hideStuff"> Getting Colder, BRRR!!! </p>
        <p class="gotIt hideStuff"> Awesome! You have guessed the number </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

What I want to do is change the text displayed in that  tag with class = "value" to something. I've tried using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         $('.query').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').css("value", "whoa");
            });
            });
```

but it is not working. I also tried to use the .css method and assign a value to the input but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

try with `.attr()`

```
   $(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').attr("value", "whoa");
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val("whoa");
```

Comment: Just go with `.val()` -- no need to use `.attr()` IMO, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.query').on('click', function() {
        $('#guessContainer .value').val("whoa");
    });
});
```

This would work. You don't use the `.css()` function to assign a value because what you are trying to change is not a CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `val` method; you can also simplify your selector since you're using an ID:

```
$('#guessContainer input.value').val("whoa");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the value with plain JavaScript on the jQuery object:

```
$('#guessContainer').find('.value')[0].value= "whoa";
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/JF5Nd/)

Comment: find will return a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so I don't think this will work

Answer (score 0):

The value of an input has nothing to do with css. Try just setting it using

```
document.getElementByID('myInputId').value = newValue;
```

Or in JQuery

```
$('#myInputId').val(newValue);
```

So in your example you might change the on click handler function to something like this:

```
$(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val("whoa");
});
```